# How to add twig template suggestions per display mode with custom module?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I have a custom module where I am trying to use custom twig templates based on the *user* *view mode*. The templates files I am trying to add to my theme are:

- `user.html.twig`
- `user--compact.html.twig`
- `user--token.html.twig`

These reside in a folder called `MYMODULE/templates/`.

This is my current module code:

**module_name.module:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return [
    'user' => [
      'template'  => 'user',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
    'user__compact' => [
      'template'  => 'user--compact',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
    'user__token' => [
      'template'  => 'user--token',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
  ];

}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I've added to my question, hopefully that helps clarify.

Comment: If it helps, when I ```dpm($existing);``` the only base hooks are ```field```, ```field_multiple_value_form```, and ```block```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter) is more suited to alter existing suggestions.

In this case, if you are just adding a suggestion, not altering the pre-existing ones, you could use the [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_user(array $variables) {
  return [
    'user__' . $variables['elements']['#view_mode']
  ];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return [
    'user' => [
      'template'  => 'user',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
    'user__compact' => [
      'template'  => 'user--compact',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
    'user__token' => [
      'template'  => 'user--token',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: Hey Cesar, you first mentioned the alter hook but then used the bare suggestion hook in the sample. I switched the snippet to use the alter hook. OP added hook_theme. I hope that's OK for you, if not please reroll the edits back to an older revision. Nice answer. :)

Comment: Hi @leymannx, the `hook_theme` part is not really needed, let me just delete that bit and explain it.

Comment: Seems OP just clarified they want to have the templates living in their module's templates folder, not in the theme. I guess that changes the initial situation.

Answer (score 3):

The fix was ensuring to add the theme suggestions via [`HOOK_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x), as well as switching one template from `user` to `user__full`. Below is the updated module code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_user_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {

  $view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
  $suggestions[] = 'user__' . $view_mode;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return [
    'user__full'    => [
      'template'  => 'user--full',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
    'user__compact' => [
      'template'  => 'user--compact',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
    'user__token'   => [
      'template'  => 'user--token',
      'base hook' => 'user',
    ],
  ];
}
```